# Read line and compare string

Tags: bash

Trying to create a bash script which reads in a file (argument 1) line by line. The script will only echo the line if it contains a keyword which matches one of the search strings. So far what I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash
searchString1="TASK"
searchString2="WD's"

while read line
do
    name=$line
    if [[ $searchString1 == *"$name"* ]] ; 
    then
        echo $name;
    elif [[ $searchString2 == *"$name"* ]] ; 
    then
        echo $name;
    fi 
done < $1
```

Script is run as:

```
chmod +x parser_script.sh
./parser_script.sh filename.txt
```

This bash script is not detecting the search strings.
Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: It is probably way faster to do all of this in an awk one-liner: `awk '/TASK/ || /WD\'s/' file`.

Comment: @fedorqui the apostrophe in `WD's` will need special handling (`'\''` -- escaping inside singly-quoted strings doesn't work), or the whole thing needs to be in double quotes: `awk "/TASK/ || /WD's/" file`. Or `grep "TASK\|WD's" file`. I like `grep`. But yes, all of that seems much easier than doing it in plain bash.

Comment: @Etan, @ hek2mgl - bash and shebang updated. No error but search strings are still not being detected correctly

Comment: What do you mean "no error"? Specifying bash fixed the `[[` problem then?

Comment: @Wintermute fedorqui, that worked thanks!.. however it would still be nice how to do this in bash :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests are backwards.

```
if [[ $name == *"$searchString1"* ]]; then
    echo $name
elif [[ $name == *"$searchString2"* ]]; then
    echo $name
fi
```

Other ways to write this:

```
if [[ $name == *"$searchString1"* ]] ||
   [[ $name == *"$searchString2"* ]]
then
    echo $name;
fi 

case $name in
    *"$searchString1"*|*"$searchString2"*)
        echo $name
        ;;
esac
```

As mentioned in the comments, you could do this with a single `grep` or `awk` call.